# Laravel doesn't support DELETE & PUT requests?

Tags: php, laravel, rest

Building my `API` it turned out, that if I am using `DELETE` or `PUT` requests Laravel throws `405 Error` `(Method Not Allowed)`. How to make it work?

Laravel error:

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
>   The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel does support DELETE and PUT. You defined your route wrong, it only allows GET-Requests.

```
Route::put('/put', 'Controller@function');
Route::delete('/delete', 'Controller@function');
```

[See docs here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#basic-routing)